# Java Objects and internal values

Tags: java, oop, domain-driven-design, aggregate, behavior

I am doing some diving into the object oriented world and trying to apply the principles of how the authors of the book Clean Code think a rich object should be constructed.

However, I have run into a somewhat philosophical problem now and I am not too sure about how to deal with representation of an object.

In the book Clean Code you can read that a rich object should only expose behaviors and never its internal variables. This statement has other sources as well.

But if you only expose behaviors, how do you then show a representation of the object in a GUI, if you can't reach the values of the internal variables?

Example:

```
public class Todo {

    private final TodoID id;
    private final String createdBy;
    private final String currentOwner;
    private final String description;
    private final Status status;

    private Todo(String createdBy, DateTime creationDate, String description, Status status, String todoName) {
        this.id = new TodoID(creationDate, todoName);
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
                this.currentOwner = createdBy;
        this.description = description;
        this.status = status;

    }

    public void startWorking(String name){
        if(Status.IN_PROGRESS > this.status){
        // Set status to IN_PROGRESS
        // Set current owner to name    
        } else {
          throw new RuntimeException(this.currentOwner + " has already started working on this task or it might be finished already.");
    }

    public static TodoID create(TodoValues values) {
        Todo todo = new Todo(values.createdBy, 
                             values.creationDate, 
                             values.description, 
                             values.status, 
                             values.todoName);
        // Operations to save the Todo-instance in a database
        return todo.id;
    }

}
```

I might have a method on my Todo-aggregate root that returns a list of all new Todo's
`public List<Todo> listAllNewTodos(){}`.
All the Todo's in the list have id's that represents the object. But how do I make a representation of the id's if an object is only allowed to expose behaviors?

**EDIT:** Right after posting this question I got a revelation. The book Clean Code also talks about that there is another type of structure in OOP. Not only objects with behaviors, but also data structures. 
In this case I should probably view the Todo-class/instances as objects and the TodoID-instances as data structures that exposes its internal variables. And thanks to that I CAN represent the Todo, with the TodoID-variables, in a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right, you should use Getters and Setters to reach the internal variables

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html

Comment: In this case I don't need the getters and setters since I don't want to expose the internal variables of the Todo-class. 

But you are right, to comply with the Bean-definition, there should be getters and setters. (But this is also something I am trying to question in my experiment. An immutable rich object that only exposes behaviors and an immutable data structure does not really need getters. It is more straight forward to directly access the public final variables, instead of going through a method that does the same thing for you).

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look into property change events.  Using this mechanism your UI doesn't have to read the values, they are sent to the UI by the object whenever they change.

Comment: You are absolutely spot on. That is one way to do it. Something I forgot to mention in the question is that the example is supposed to be on a level below the UI, only containing the logic. But this layer should also be producing events such as propery changed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not all class variables might be "internal variables". You can consider a variable internal if it is used by some behavior in your class but not needed by the consumers of your class.

In your example, suppose that, you need to keep total time for each ToDo item and users can start a task multiple times. Then, you would need to declare an internal variable:

```
private Date latestStartTime;
```

Clearly, this variable should be used by startWorking and pause methods (which I didn't include) but will not be provided to calling methods. For other fields, you can provide getter methods (and setter methods when your fields are not final) as @Gynnad has recommended. You can use them in UI.

There might be other (and better) solutions, such as the one you mentioned in your edit. Just remember, these are all heuristics to create better code, not hard rules.

Comment: Very good, valid and interesting point you are making. That is something I will have to think about, but it is very tempting to make that difference on the variables, that only those that aren't needed by a consumer are to be viewed as internal.
I understand that it is all guidelines to create better code and not hard rules, but by acting as if they are hard rules it makes me really think about every decision. Every rule I want to break makes me question the rule and find good reasons for it. If I can't find a good reason for a rule or a good reason to break it, then I won't do it.

Comment: You might want to read this discussion at C2 wiki as well: [C2Wiki Accessors Are Evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AccessorsAreEvil)

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html)?

You would split up the tasks the user can do and the information he needs on a screen:

When a user wants to do something, you don't need to have internal state:

```
public class StartWorkingOnTodoCommandHandler : CommandHandler<StartWorkingOnTodoCommand>
{
    public void handle(StartWorkingOnTodoCommand command)
    {
        Todo todo = session.get<Todo>(command.getId());
        User user = session.get<User>(command.getUserId());
        todo.startWorking(user);
    }
}
```

and when you want to get query for information, you can create a separate layer:

```
public class UnfinishedTodo
{
    public String getTitle()
    {
    }

    public TodoId getId()
    {
    }

    public String getCreatedBy()
    {
    }
}
```

(My Java is getting a bit rusty)

Here it will be possible (I don't know if it is wanted) to have a User domain object in your Todo, but still have a String back to the UI.

Answer (score 0):

> In the book Clean Code you can read that a rich object should only
>   expose behaviors and never its internal variables. This statement has
>   other sources as well.
>
> But if you only expose behaviors, how do you then show a
>   representation of the object in a GUI, if you can't reach the values
>   of the internal variables?

This is because that the rich objects in the book Clean code are **not** designed for displaying in GUI, but for protecting invariants. In your case, the business rule is not very complex and the TODO class is also responsible for query requirements, so it's fine to have some getter methods for now.